# How to run a script on the host targeting each container that's running after 'docker-compose up -d'

Tags: docker, sh, hardening

I'm trying to follow CIS Security Benchmark for Docker containers and there are checks like *"Use `--pids-limit` flag with an appropriate value when launching the container"* that I can't do if I'm using version 3 of docker-compose.

So I was thinking on running a script that would do `docker container update --pids-limit 1234 <container-name>` but ran into the issue of getting the container's name from docker-compose in an automated way, so that it runs for every service listed on the yml.

Comment: Unclear what more you want than `docker-compose ps | grep <service>`

Comment: If I'm grepping by the service name, I could just use the service name straight into the script. To be more clear, I want to have the script to run for each service listed on the yml as they go up.

Comment: "As they go up" would require compose to have some execution callback hook to know when the container transitions between states. If you really want that level of control, I suggest using the Golang/Python Compose _Client_ rather than shell scripts

Comment: Compose file format v2 is still supported, and supports more of the detailed `docker run` options that aren't appropriate for Swarm (including [`pids_limit:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#pids_limit)).  Would that better match your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze if i had the option to go back to v2, I would for sure. It seems that the way to go is using the Python/Golang API as Cricketeer suggestedd.